# Cancel button in UITextfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Anyone a clue for this problem?

[image]

thats how i create it

```
    //create the textfield
CGRect frameTxt = CGRectMake(10, 12, 280, 30);
txtFavouriteName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frameTxt];
txtFavouriteName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txtFavouriteName.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
txtFavouriteName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and thats how i add it to the proper tableview cell

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.txtFavouriteName];
```

i want to align this cancel button vertical middle

second question is maybe a simpler one. how can i change the textcolor of the header text from this boring grey to whit?

Anyone a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
CGRect frameTxt = CGRectMake(10, 12, 280, 25);
```

Also to change the header text you cannot use tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
You need to use a UILabel, which you can plug in your font, size, color and string and plug it into self.tableView.tableHeaderView.